# A drop down menu with checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to make a drop down menu with checkbox like this :

Before click : [image: before click]

After click : [image: after click]

Do you have an idea please (it's an ASP.NET project and I'm using some jquery script)

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I've got a lot of ideas. Now show us your code with a problem description, or at least show some effort indicating you're trying to help yourself in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a dropdown with checkboxes using jquery:

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/
Click the "demo" folder to see an example of it.

And here is an example using a custom .net control:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24205/MultiSelect-Dropdown-Control

Comment: I guess the plugin is not maintained up to date anymore...it is archived.

Comment: Thanks, I will using jquery-multiselect because the second solution is more difficult ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically u can use [PopupControl](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx)

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Id="Panel1">
here is your content1
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" Id="Panel2">
here is your content2
</asp:Panel>

<ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Panel1"
    PopupControlID="Panel2"
Position="Bottom" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I thinks that I will using jQuery but I discover ajaxToolKit with it lol

Answer (score 0):

You want [Jquery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

Check out [demo](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)